# Python sharedmem access from Lua

Tags: python, numpy, lua, shared-memory

I have to repeatedly move a large array from Lua to Python. Currently, I run the Lua code as a subprocess from Python and read the array from its stdout. This is much slower than I'd like, and the bottleneck seems to be almost entirely the Python `p.stdout.read([byte size of array])` calls, as running the Lua code in isolation is much faster.

From what I have read, the only way to improve over pipes is to use shared memory, but this is (almost) always discussed in regards to multiprocessing between different Python processes instead of between Python and a subprocess.

Is there a reasonable way to share memory between Python and Lua? Related answers have suggested using direct calls to [shm_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_unlink.3.html) but I'd rather use prebuilt modules/packages if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found using Torch from Lua and NumPy from Python. The Lua code is run from Python using lupa.

In `main.lua`:

```
require 'torch'

data_array = torch.FloatTensor(256, 256)

function write_data()
    return tonumber(torch.data(data_array:contiguous(), true))
end
```

From Python:

```
import ctypes
import lupa
import numpy as np

data_shape = (256, 256)

lua = lupa.LuaRuntime()
with open('main.lua') as f: lua.execute(f.read())
data_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_void_p(lua.globals().write_data()), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)), shape=data_shape)
```

`data_array` is constructed to point at the storage of the Torch tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Before going down the path of looking into shared memory I would suggest doing some profiling experiments to identify exactly where the time is being spent.

If your experiments prove you're spending too much time serializing/deserializing data between the processes then using shared memory along with a format designed to avoid that cost like [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/) could be a good solution.

A quick search turned up these two libraries:

- [lua-capnproto](https://github.com/cloudflare/lua-capnproto) - 
  Lua-capnp is a pure lua implementation of capnproto based on luajit.
- [pycapnp](https://jparyani.github.io/pycapnp/) - This is a python wrapping of the C++ implementation of the Cap’n Proto library.

But definitely do the profiling first.

Also is there a reason [lupa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa/) wouldn't work for you?.

Comment: I really needed the data as a numpy array (requires it is contiguous in memory), and lupa didn't solve that issue.

Comment: I see.  I missed the numpy requirement.  [This fork of lupa](https://github.com/cstraehl/lupa) claims to support numpy although the commits that work with ndarray are from 2012.  However this comment is promising: https://github.com/scoder/lupa/issues/73#issuecomment-216502216

Comment: Lupa did remove the need for pipes though, which is good. I included it in my answer.

Comment: There's near zero overhead either way since it's only passing across a pointer to the data. The main good thing lupa allows in this case is calling Lua functions directly instead of building a protocol for calling them across a pipe.